# Discord.py Cannot find reference "RequestsWebhookAdapter"

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to import RequestsWebhook Adapter for my python project and it just won't install the RequestsWebhookAdapter
pip Discord.py version: 1.7.3

Python version: 3.10.6

Code:

```
import requests
import discord
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter # Importing discord.RequestsWebhookAdapter doesnt work

webhook = Webhook.from_url('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[my-webhook]', adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter()) # Initializing webhook
webhook.send(content="Hello World") # Executing webhook.
```

How do I get requests webhook adapter? I dont want to use async stuff

Answer (score 3):

With the new release of discord package, you have to update your code to:

```
import requests
from discord import SyncWebhook # Import SyncWebhook

webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[my-webhook]') # Initializing webhook
webhook.send(content="Hello World") # Executing webhook.
```

Answer (score 1):

Today was new release of discord.py package. Downgrade it to 1.7.3 and everything will be fine :)

So.. in your requirements.txt should be:

```
discord==1.7.3
discord.py==1.7.3
```

Comment: Did RequestsWebhookAdapter move in the new release? Staying with the old version isn't always a wise choice.